# splash screen not working on Samsung galaxy android 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova

I am facing one typical issue where our application(built with cordova 3.4.0) working for all versions from 2.3.x to 4.4.x however on following device because of splash screen plugin the app is not able to load

Samsung Android SGH-1747M

Version 4.1.1

When we remove splash plugin it works fine.

Issue : We have a splash screen open for 30 seconds before we redirect user to our login page (load from server side)

If we add splash plugin it doesn't load the login page it shows half black and half white screen forever, but if i remove splash screen plugin it works.For all other versions app working fine with splash screen plugin.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Since its 4.1.1 i am not able to get stack trace or logging statements  on aLogcat , but below is the onCreate method that we have

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (appView == null) {
            init();
        }
        appView.setWebChromeClient(new CordovaChromeClient(this, appView));
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        super.loadUrl(getString(R.string.app_url), 30000);
    }
```

and using the same cordova pluing for splash screen as standard one (cordova version 3.4.0)

```
<preference
 name="SplashScreen"
 value="splash"/>
```

Comment: stacktrace? code? plugin?

Comment: Thanks... added -- More information--- on my original post